# Why is Google Cloud Vision api unable to detect text in a particular pdf file although it works fine on a very similar pdf?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision

The google cloud vision api works fine on one pdf [pdf1](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1lBajk7rSUq_NSj3x9AZEJh7ZD6EVgcGu) but returns absolutely nothing on the other pdf [pdf2](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1BGN_QwMqwLZQY59DlpdC9EA56H5QmYoa). I'm unable to make sense of this behavior as both the pdfs are very similar and have almost the same font.Please help.

I'm using the code given in their examples section by uploading these files in a google cloud bucket.

```
def async_detect_document(gcs_source_uri, gcs_destination_uri):
    """OCR with PDF/TIFF as source files on GCS"""
    from google.cloud import vision
    from google.cloud import storage
    from google.protobuf import json_format
    # Supported mime_types are: 'application/pdf' and 'image/tiff'
    mime_type = 'application/pdf'

    # How many pages should be grouped into each json output file.
    batch_size = 2

    client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()

    feature = vision.types.Feature(
        type=vision.enums.Feature.Type.DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION)

    gcs_source = vision.types.GcsSource(uri=gcs_source_uri)
    input_config = vision.types.InputConfig(
        gcs_source=gcs_source, mime_type=mime_type)

    gcs_destination = vision.types.GcsDestination(uri=gcs_destination_uri)
    output_config = vision.types.OutputConfig(
        gcs_destination=gcs_destination, batch_size=batch_size)

    async_request = vision.types.AsyncAnnotateFileRequest(
        features=[feature], input_config=input_config,
        output_config=output_config)

    operation = client.async_batch_annotate_files(
        requests=[async_request])

    print('Waiting for the operation to finish.')
    operation.result(timeout=180)

    # Once the request has completed and the output has been
    # written to GCS, we can list all the output files.
    storage_client = storage.Client()

    match = re.match(r'gs://([^/]+)/(.+)', gcs_destination_uri)
    bucket_name = match.group(1)
    prefix = match.group(2)

    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name=bucket_name)

    # List objects with the given prefix.
    blob_list = list(bucket.list_blobs(prefix=prefix))
    print('Output files:')
    for blob in blob_list:
        print(blob.name)

    # Process the first output file from GCS.
    # Since we specified batch_size=2, the first response contains
    # the first two pages of the input file.
    output = blob_list[0]

    json_string = output.download_as_string()
    response = json_format.Parse(
        json_string, vision.types.AnnotateFileResponse())

    # The actual response for the first page of the input file.
    first_page_response = response.responses[0]
    annotation = first_page_response.full_text_annotation

    # Here we print the full text from the first page.
    # The response contains more information:
    # annotation/pages/blocks/paragraphs/words/symbols
    # including confidence scores and bounding boxes
    print(u'Full text:\n{}'.format(
        annotation.text))
```

Answer (score 0):

It probably has nothing to do with the GCloud API, I tried uploading your pdf to [the vision drag and drop](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/drag-and-drop) website and it returns expected results. Maybe at some point in your pipeline, the pdf is corrupted in any way? what does it look like in gcloud storage?

Answer (score 0):

we also faced this issue and after doing few experiments it seems to me this is due to some font google vision not able to support. 
To solve this generate pdf to image and then send image to process will provide result.